# How to add a string to a file with the execution of a regular expression?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
import re
import logging

x = input("enter number of bad car")
if re.match('/^[A-ZА-Я]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-ZА-Я]{2}([0-9]{0,3})?$/', x):
  logging.debug("found match" + x)
  with open("some.txt" , 'w') as f:
    f.write(x + '\n')
    else:
      logging.debug("does not match")
```

However, nothing is written in the file some.txt

Comment: Is your regex matching? Do you see the log 'found match x' or 'does not match'? -- note your else statement is over indented

Comment: remove the regex delimiters first.

Comment: You should be able to narrow it down yourself step by step. Output x. See which part fails.

Answer (score 1):

I got a logging file which wrote away 'does not match' with the following changes:

```
import re
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename = ( "loggingfile.log"), level = logging.DEBUG, format = '%(message)s')

x = input("enter number of bad car")
if re.match('/^[A-ZА-Я]{1}[0-9]{3}[A-ZА-Я]{2}([0-9]{0,3})?$/', x):
  logging.debug("found match" + x)
  with open("some.txt" , 'w') as f:
    needed = str(x + '\n')
    logging.info(needed)
else:
    logging.info("does not match")
```

So, I added:

1. `logging.basicConfig`, which set some basic configuration stuff
   for your logging file (name, path, format...)
2. I created `needed` up front, which has all the needed data in it, and then wrote it away to the logging file using `logging.info()`

I think that that is all that I changed, hope I helped out!

I got output like this from 'logging.log' with input (the random number) `56184615`:

```
does not match
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex cannot match. `/^' means a slash, followed by the start of the string. Try to remove the two slashes in the regex.